# Who is "Nine Lives Man"? (Push Comic) bronze sculpture

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, art

On the platform of [Liujia train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liujia_railway_station) in Hsinchu county Taiwan there is what looks like a bronze sculpture of someone riding or flying a stylized retro or steampunk rocket motorcycle with a small cat-like(?) animal on their back.

At the base of the sculpture there is an inscription, the English part reads:

> Push Comic ©2014 Nine Lives Man, Art Team: Sunny Chen, Tobeby.

and the beginning part might be Chinese or Japanese

Any idea who this is or if there is a story behind it?

[image: "Nine Lives Man" Liujia train station, Hsinchu]

click images for full size

[image: "Nine Lives Man" Liujia train station, Hsinchu] [image: "Nine Lives Man" Liujia train station, Hsinchu]

[image: "Nine Lives Man" Liujia train station, Hsinchu] [image: "Nine Lives Man" Liujia train station, Hsinchu]

Comment: https://pushcomic.pixnet.net/blog/post/28617112

Comment: https://www.yumpu.com/xx/document/read/62893601/nine-lives-mannew-edition-ah-tui-push-comic

Comment: I was on the verge of downvoting for a lack of research effort. It's pretty easy to find out who "Nine Lives Man" is by just googling it.

Comment: Although understanding the Chinese might be a bit more tricky for some. :)

Comment: @Valorum it is not easy for me at all. Each person has different limitations.

Comment: https://hkac.org.hk/calendar_detail/?u=_sarxwCgirU might be handy for an English article.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots on the front of the vehicle in the sculpture there is a circular fixture with three hemispheres on it. I noticed that there is a humanoid in a jacket with those three hemispheres on their face [here](https://www.yumpu.com/xx/document/read/62893601/nine-lives-mannew-edition-ah-tui-push-comic). I can't figure out what's going on at all.

Comment: @uhoh: Honestly, I'm not certain either. I don't read Chinese. Side note, some of the blog posts about it seem to indicate it's a bit of an absurdist comic full of background gags, so there might not be much meaning to it.

Comment: @uhoh It is just a chinese  novel published from 1986 chinese

Comment: @someoneuseless *Thanks!* Did the novel have artwork that looked like this? If not, there might be a related comic book as well.

Comment: Not sure I dont have it. Here is the syponsis (not totally accurate) in care you are wondering:

The story of the "Nine Lives" protagonist Mong Jugo was originally just a ordinary business chief. He accept a mysterious mission for a lucrative reward, but was shot and raised to the fairy nest and was selected by the fairies as the subject of life experiments. The fairy gave him nine lives, each time with a completely different identity, once turned into a dog, once turned into a computer machine, once turned into a tree, and even became the king of hell!

Comment: Here is the link https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B9%9D%E5%91%BD%E4%BA%BA `
`九命人` - Nine lives man.
`阿推` - the 1st 2 letter in your picture is the author name.

Comment: @someoneuseless https://www.gaeaoriginal.com.tw/2020/02/12 and/or https://www.cna.com.tw/news/acul/202003210236.aspx ?

Comment: @uhoh Both talk about same thing the first one is the manga history. Now I get it was a manhua from the start. It is popular because it is the only manhua about scifi when there is only wuxia in 80s.He make it in 1985 then he end it now regroup his other 2 manga with this new one and make a triology.

The 2nd one is his work all 3 of them MC name means nine btw in chinese.

Comment: @someoneuseless Thanks, I think you can post that as an answer!

Comment: Dont know the story, but that looks more like a cat on his back that a dog to me. (Cant think of any dogs that can curl their tale like that either.)  Also that left eye looks like a cat's eye (vertical slit)

Comment: @NJohnny oh my gosh I see what you mean! I didn't even notice there was a face. I looked at the body shape and length of legs, (especially fourth picture) but didn't notice that it's wearing some kind of a jacket. I've updated the text accordingly, *thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just about manhua 九命人 "Nine lives Man" from "[阿推](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%98%BF%E6%8E%A8)".

Info taken from this [page](http://gaeaoriginal.com.tw/2020/02/12) and this [page](http://cna.com.tw/news/acul/202003210236.aspx)

This manhua from the start is popular because it is the only manhua about scifi when there is only wuxia in 80s. He make it in 1985 then he end it now regroup his other 2 manga with this new one and make a triology.

Here is the translated version of [syponysis](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B9%9D%E5%91%BD%E4%BA%BA) (not accurate)

> The story of the "Nine Lives" protagonist Mong Jugo was originally just a ordinary business chief. He accept a mysterious mission for a lucrative reward, but was shot and raised to the fairy nest and was selected by the fairies as the subject of life experiments. The fairy gave him nine lives, each time with a completely different identity, once turned into a dog, once turned into a computer machine, once turned into a tree, and even became the king of hell

> 《九命人》的故事主角蒙九戈原本只是一间生意普通的侦探社的社长，为了丰厚的酬劳而接受了一项神秘任务，不料却遭到枪杀升上神仙窝并被神仙选中作生命实验的对象。神仙让他拥有了九条命，每一次都以完全不同的生命表征出现，有一次变成狗，有一次变成电脑机械，有一次变成是树，甚至是变成地狱王

Comment: Yes it is different from chinese and japanese comic. Wuxia is a genre likely talk about adventure in martial society feature qi force, ancient warrior,... Later on with some isekai and higher power it become xuanhuan.

Comment: @uhoh As a rule of thumb, in the western world there are three established terms for asian comics: "Manga" for comics from Japan, "manwha" for comics from (South) Korea and "manhua" for comics from China. The characteristics, commonalities and differences of each of the three could probably fill several thesis papers ;) It should also be noted that the three terms are more to describe stylistic and cultural aspects than strictly geographical aspects. Therefore, a manga / manwha / manhua may as well be created by an artist in Europe or in the US.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck wow I didn't know any of that, thanks for the thorough tutorial! Since comments are considered temporary and could be deleted some day, I wonder if asking something like "Difference between Manga, Manwah and Manhua for novices?" would be worth asking here, or something similar in meta? That way it can be captured and pointed-to later.

Comment: @uhoh That seems more like a Meta question to me.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots done! [What are distinctions between manga, manhua  and manwha as they relate to this site? How to know which to use, and how to tag?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13143/51174)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck A comment under the meta post points to [What's the difference between manga, manhwa, and manhua?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7004) in Anime SE, and my goodness it seems insufficiently-answered!